# does Laravel have choices in model? like Django

Tags: django, laravel

I'm wondering does Laravel have something like Django choices in models?

for example in Django: [Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/)

```
class Card(models.Model):

    class Suit(models.IntegerChoices):
        DIAMOND = 1
        SPADE = 2
        HEART = 3
        CLUB = 4

    suit = models.IntegerField(choices=Suit.choices)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Enums`, a new Feature for `PHP 8.1`.

```
enum Suit:integer
{
    case DIAMOND = 1;
    case SPADE = 2;
    case HEART = 3;
    case CLUB = 4;
}
```

In your model.

```
class Card extend Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'suit' => Suit::class,
    ];
}
```

Now when creating a card you can use the `enum`.

```
$card->fill(['suit' => Suit::DIAMOND]);
```

Or from input.

```
$card->fill(['suit' => Suit::from($request->get('suit'))]);
```

The documentation on Enums can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.enumerations.php).